# Несколько public классов в одном .class-файле

Tags: java

По какой причине нельзя создать несколько public-классов в одном .java-файле? Почему можно создавать без модификатора доступа?

P.S. Заранее извиняюсь за, возможно, глупый вопрос, но не смог найти ответ в Интернете.

Comment: Ответ простой - каждый файл должен отвечать только за один класс, также как и каждый класс должен реализовывать только одну логическую задачу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таково соглашение Java: публичный класс (`public class`) должен размещаться в 1-м файле название которого совпадает с именем класса.

Непубличные классы (классы с объявлением без слова `public`) могут размещаться сколько угодно в 1-м файле.

В сети можно прочитать множество теорий почему это так со всякими разными дурацкими версиями, но на самом деле все гораздо проще - это всего лишь соглашение: [File Organization Convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html#3043)

Лишним подтверждением того, что это всего лишь соглашение служит тот простой факт - 
в Kotlin и C# этого ограничения нет - там можно по всякому разному.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что .class файлы - это результат работы компилятора. Эти файлы создаются компилятором на основе файлов с вашим кодом (source файлы, которые как правило .java), в которых вы в свою очередь можете объявить несколько классов в одном файле.

В Java существует 4 **области видимости** (private, public, protected, package-private). **Модификаторов** области видимости же 3(private, public, protected). Модификатор нужен чтобы определить зону видимости и он не обязателен - в этом случае устанавливается область видимости по умолчанию - package-private.